# Robot Framework Download File

Tags: html, testing, download, robotframework

I use the Robot Framework.

On my HTML page I have a simple button. When you click on it, it downloads a PDF file.

How can I check with Robot Framework if the file has been downloaded?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution is very browser specific. For Chrome, you can tell Chrome where to download files. Choosing a new folder allows you to monitor the status of the download. Also, since you are downloading a PDF, disabling the PDF plugin is necessary to prevent the PDF from being displayed instead of downloaded. Here is a test that worked on my machine using a simple page and PDF file.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Download PDF
    # create unique folder
    ${now}    Get Time    epoch
    ${download directory}    Join Path    ${OUTPUT DIR}    downloads_${now}
    Create Directory    ${download directory}
    ${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    # list of plugins to disable. disabling PDF Viewer is necessary so that PDFs are saved rather than displayed
    ${disabled}    Create List    Chrome PDF Viewer
    ${prefs}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${download directory}    plugins.plugins_disabled=${disabled}
    Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
    Goto    http://localhost/download.html
    Click Link    link    # downloads a file
    # wait for download to finish
    ${file}    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    1 min    2 sec    Download should be done    ${download directory}

*** Keywords ***
Download should be done
    [Arguments]    ${directory}
    [Documentation]    Verifies that the directory has only one folder and it is not a temp file.
    ...
    ...    Returns path to the file
    ${files}    List Files In Directory    ${directory}
    Length Should Be    ${files}    1    Should be only one file in the download folder
    Should Not Match Regexp    ${files[0]}    (?i).*\\.tmp    Chrome is still downloading a file
    ${file}    Join Path    ${directory}    ${files[0]}
    Log    File was successfully downloaded to ${file}
    [Return]    ${file}
```

Contents of download.html:

```
<html><body><a href="file.pdf" id="link">Click Here</a></body></html>
```

Comment: IE is possible to do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
${home_dir}         Get Environment Variable    HOME
${download_dir}     Join Path   ${home_dir}     Downloads
${result}    Run Keyword And Return Status  File Should Exist   
${download_dir}/filename.pdf
```

To check further on the file 
    ${content}     Get File    ${download_dir}/filename.pdf
    ${count_file}   Get Line Count    ${content}

Above can be used for basic assertion 
For more keywords please check the link http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it is to capture and store timestamp before clicking on download and after clicking download, keep checking the folder if a file exists with timestamp later than the stored one(before download is clicked Tstamp). This works when you do not know the name of the file.

Even if you know the file, when run Test case again, file with named as download(1).pdf as previous file exists in the folder.

```
*** Settings ***
# Library    Selenium2Library
Library   checkdownload.py
*** Test Cases ***
Download file Check TC
    [Documentation]  TC to Check file download button is working
    ${now}    Get Time    epoch
    #Click on download button #add here
    Sleep    30s
    ${res}    Check Download    ${now}
    Log    ${res}
```

Create a py file and add in robot test suite

```
#checkdownload.py
import os
import glob
import getpass
from datetime import datetime

def Check_download(timestamp):
    user_name=getpass.getuser()
    default_download_path=r'/Users/'+user_name+'/Downloads/*' #for mac
    # default_download_path=r'C:\Users\\'+user_name+'\Downloads\*' #windows

    files_list=glob.glob(default_download_path) 
    for i in files_list:
        if(timestamp < os.path.getctime(i)):
            return i
    return False
```

Below are test results (simulated the download)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this using FOR IN with large number for every file (when you don't know size and how much time will take to download it).
e.g.

```
${range}    Set Variable    9999999 
FOR ${s}    IN RANGE    ${range}
${status}   Run Keyword And Return Status   File Should Not Exist ${path}\\*.zip.part
Sleep 60
```

So the script is checking every 60sec if download is finished (no *.zip.part (for FF browser) in particular download folder) then exit for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Create WebDriver - you can use simply use Open Browser Keyword to change the download directory using options arguments. Please use a relative path instead of a given absolute path.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary     
 
*** Test Cases ***
DownloadDirectoryChangeForSession
       ${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=C:\\Balaji
       Open Browser    url=https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/    browser=chrome    options=add_experimental_option("prefs",${prefs})
       Maximize Browser Window
       Click Element    partial link=32 bit
       File Should Exist    C:\\Components\\chromedriver_win32.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me fine (declare the the download path as a variable)

```
${prefs}=       Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY}
SeleniumLibrary.Open browser    ${URL}    ${browser} 
   options=add_experimental_option("prefs", ${prefs})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the MD5 of the file - before download and after download.
Both the MD5 should be same.

Assuming file is on Linux machine - before and after download :

1. Login to linux machine using SSH library
2. Run the command :    #md5sum  PATH_TO_FILE
3. Store the output in a variable.
4. Compare the variable value

Hope so this information was helpful.