# Replace sleep with wait keyword on RobotFramework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

In a test case is used the keyword `sleep 2s`
and this is obviously too slow, so i would like to replace with the `wait` keyword.

Thing is, that it is used for a download. So the user downloads a file and then is used the `sleep 2s` in order to give some time to the Robot Framework to complete the download.

But I cannot use

`wait until element is visible,
 wait until page contains, 
or wait until page contains element`

because nothing changes on the page :/

Any ideas? How you handle this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you see that the file is already downloaded?

Comment: And what do you mean saying "too slow"?

Comment: usually the waiting moments are about 300ms-500ms so 2s is bigger amount of time and probably not necessary.
I see it on my browser manually eg firefox has the error showing down marked as blue. Or on Chrome, on the bar at the bottom. But I have no idea how to capture such action with Robot :/

Comment: Why don't you use `sleep 500ms` or `sleep 1s`?

Comment: I want to avoid `sleep`, for example see the Avoid Sleeping in herE: [link](https://github.com/robotframework/HowToWriteGoodTestCases/blob/master/HowToWriteGoodTestCases.rst#avoid-sleeping)

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297958/robot-framework-download-file

Comment: But I also don't know how much to wait for a download 'cause it depends on internet connection & size of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the keyword of `wait until keyword succeeds`and just keep repeating the next keyword you want to use until the download is done. Or you could set the implicit wait time to be higher so the webdriver waits for an implicit amount of time before it executes another keyword.

Comment: Yeah probably this is ehat i have done. Although it's been more than year ago :) thank you for your respond!