# How can I enable download a file using a headless chrome browser in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

How can i use Page.setDownloadBehavior in chrome dev tools to pass on so that I can set the download behavior for headless chrome with the code below?

```
    Create Chrome Browser
    [Arguments]    ${link_to_open}
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${prefs}=    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${DOWNLOADS_DIR}
   Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    headless 
   Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
  Selenium2Library.Go To    ${link_to_open}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be a 'security feature' when trying to download a file using Chrome in headless mode. This is further discussed in the [Chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481). This pointed to the StackOverflow answer for [Downloading with chrome headless and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366981/6152737). In this answer a Python example is given ([GitHub](https://github.com/shawnbutton/PythonHeadlessChrome/blob/master/driver_builder.py)) which converts easily to a Robot Framework Library:

**headless_download.py**

```
class headless_download(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def enable_download_in_headless_chrome(self, driver, download_dir):
        """
        there is currently a "feature" in chrome where
        headless does not allow file download: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481
        This method is a hacky work-around until the official chromedriver support for this.
        Requires chrome version 62.0.3196.0 or above.
        """

        # add missing support for chrome "send_command"  to selenium webdriver
        driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

        params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
        command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
        print("response from browser:")
        for key in command_result:
            print("result:" + key + ":" + str(command_result[key]))
```

When downloading a file, the StackOverlow answer for [Robot Framework Download File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35300056/6152737) that fits this example perfectly. Adding the extra lines for headless mode, additional library and a working example:

**headless_download.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem
Library           headless_download

*** Test Cases ***
Download PDF
  # create unique folder
  ${now}    Get Time    epoch
  ${download directory}    Join Path    ${OUTPUT DIR}    downloads_${now}
  Create Directory    ${download directory}

  ${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver

  # list of plugins to disable. disabling PDF Viewer is necessary so that PDFs are saved rather than displayed
  ${disabled}    Create List    Chrome PDF Viewer
  ${prefs}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${download directory}    plugins.plugins_disabled=${disabled}
  Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}

  Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    headless 
  Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    disable-gpu

  Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}

  Go To    http://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-text-file.php

  ${S2L}           get library instance    Selenium2Library
  ${webdriver}    Call Method             ${S2L}    _current_browser
  Enable Download In Headless Chrome    ${webdriver}    ${download directory} 

  Click Link    xpath=//a[@data='1']

  # wait for download to finish
  ${file}    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    1 min    2 sec    Download should be done    ${download directory}

*** Keywords ***
Download should be done
  [Arguments]    ${directory}
  [Documentation]    Verifies that the directory has only one folder and it is not a temp file.
  ...
  ...    Returns path to the file
  ${files}    List Files In Directory    ${directory}
  Length Should Be    ${files}    1    Should be only one file in the download folder
  Should Not Match Regexp    ${files[0]}    (?i).*\\.tmp    Chrome is still downloading a file
  ${file}    Join Path    ${directory}    ${files[0]}
  Log    File was successfully downloaded to ${file}
  [Return]    ${file}
```

So, in short: this answer was not possible without the contributions by others on Stack Overflow. If this provides you with a working solution, please follow the links to the other answers and upvote those answers as well.

Comment: Hi A. Kootstra,

Ive tried the python calls but I am still unsuccessful. I got this on the logs:

18:08:46.018 DEBUG POST http://127.0.0.1:52532/session/c5aa448ceadbb7c41fb1de629a23283c/chromium/send_command {"sessionId": "c5aa448ceadbb7c41fb1de629a23283c", "params": {"downloadPath": "C:\\Temp\\Downloads", "behavior": "allow"}, "cmd": "Page.setDownloadBehavior"} 
18:08:46.034 DEBUG Finished Request 
result:value:None
result:status:0 

Is this normal? It was still unable to download. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Which version of Selenium(2)Library, Selenium Python Module and Webdriver are you running. Is this an error from running the example as-is or did you modify it to suit your own needs?

Comment: Just tried on the example below except that i am downloading on an intranet/internal web application from my company.