# Robot framework - How to specify default download location for Chrome?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to set default download location in Chrome. Below mentioned is the code:

```
*** Variables ***
${DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY}  C:\\robot_framework\\Results
*** Keywords ***
Begin Web Test
    @{list} =  create list  disable-web-security      ignore-certificate-error
    ${args} =   create dictionary  args=${list}         download.default.directory=${DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY}
    ${desired_caps} =   create dictionary  chromeOptions=${args}
    open browser  about:blank   ${BROWSER}  desired_capabilitis=${desired_caps}
    maximize browser window
```

When executed, code run fine however chrome is still downloading file into default directory. What change I need to bring in the code ?

Comment: I can't see that `download.default.directory` is actually used. Shouldn't you add it to the desired capabilities?

Comment: i is there :   `${args} =   create dictionary  args=${list}       download.default.directory=${DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY}`

Comment: You ve got a typo there. It should be `desired_capabilities`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a piece of code that I use:

```
${chromeOptions} =    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${downloadDir}
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --lang\=${browserLocale}
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --headless
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --window-size\=1024,768
Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
${webdriverCreated} =    Run Keyword And Return Status    Create Webdriver    ${browserName}    chrome_options=${chromeOptions}
Run Keyword Unless    ${webdriverCreated}    Create Webdriver    ${browserName}    chrome_options=${chromeOptions}
```

I also had some issues when running downloads in headless Chrome. There's a workaround here if it's your case as well: [How can I enable download a file using a headless chrome browser in robot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399554/how-can-i-enable-download-a-file-using-a-headless-chrome-browser-in-robot-framew)

Answer (score 0):

```
${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()    selenium.webdriver
${normalized_path}=    Normalize Path    ${path_a_specifier}
Log To Console    ${normalized_path}
${prefs}=    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${normalized_path}
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
Open Browser    ${APP_URL}    ${Browser}    options=${chrome_options}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**